# Undo SQL Update Azure DB

Tags: sql-server

I have accidentally updated over 3,000 records in one of my tables hosted on Azure. This was not a transaction and I did not have any back ups for this table.

I've read around and found [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx?_kk=apex%20sql%20log&_kt=5343bae6-6cfb-4cf8-868a-a5227cbf16d7&gclid=Cj0KEQjw4aqgBRCvwLDi_8Tc54YBEiQAs6DLvITcbHyM7fFrpAfn19sKUIV41cUkB2lKRnE5D5OoxPoaAv8W8P8HAQ) but when I connect I try to connect I see "SQL server Azure is not supported"

I understand that this tool examines logs to reproduce the data, is there a manual technique to do is, or an alternative compatible tool?

Really grateful for you support.

Thanks.